# Should I enable cloudflare crawler hints with Yoast SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, cloudflare, yoast

I have a WordPress site, and I want to have more traffic. I already have Yoast SEO installed in WordPress. Should I also enable CloudFlare crawler hints, and can it cause security issues? I see the Bing search console also promoting it.

Answer (score 1):

Crawler Hints provide high quality data to search engines and other crawlers when sites using Cloudflare change their content. This allows crawlers to precisely time crawling, avoid wasteful crawls, and generally reduce resource consumption on origins and other Internet infrastructure.

Yes! You can safely enable this setting.

I am using it on three of my websites in conjunction with yoast SEO and it is working perfectly fine.